# How can I delete a specific object from Parse query results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

My code runs through the query results and puts them all in a list for the user to see. How can I add a delete button that deletes the object named in the list item? At the moment all the buttons only delete the last result.

```
query.exists("serviceName");
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        //clears current list
        (function($) {
            $("#service-table li").remove();
        })(jQuery);
        //retrieves  new up-to-date list
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];

            //Inserts each retrieved serviceName as a list item into the HTML
            (function($) {
                $('#service-table').append('<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge" id="delete">DELETE</span><a href="#" id="listItemService">' + object.get('serviceName') + '</a></li>');
            })(jQuery);

            //Supposed to delete the relevant object but all delete buttons delete last list item
            (function($) {
                $('#delete').on('click', function() {
                    object.destroy({
                        success: function(object) {},
                        error: function(object, error) {}
                    })
                });
            })(jQuery);
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {}
});
```

[image]

Here's an example of the list.

Comment: Parse answer is json, right ? So `delete ParseResponse[key];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of issues:

You are using the same *id* "delete" on all of your delete buttons. An *id* should be unique to one element; use a *class* when referencing more than one element. Your code assigns the same 'click' event to all elements with id="delete"; it doesn't differentiate between delete buttons. 
https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Each iteration of your for loop reassigns the variable *object* to the next element in *results*. The event you are assigning to the delete button at the end of the loop looks to the variable *object* to see what to destroy, but by the last iteration of the loop, *object* points to the last element in *results*.

One solution is to use [data-attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) to have each delete button reference the appropriate item in *results*. You can assign a *data-id* attribute to each delete button and set its value to the index of the corresponding *results* item. Then, when binding the 'click' event to the delete buttons, use *event.target* to get the clicked element's *data-id* value and destroy the appropriate object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
// Inserts each retrieved serviceName as a list item into the HTML
// Assigns i as the data-id value for each delete button
    (function($) {
        $('#service-table').append('<li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge delete" data-id=i>DELETE</span><a href="#" id="listItemService">' + object.get('serviceName') + '</a></li>');
    })(jQuery);

    (function($) {
        $('.delete').on('click', function(event) {
            // Gets the value of the clicked delete button's data-id attribute
            var dataID = $(event.target).attr('data-id');
            // Finds the results item whose index is dataID
            var object = results[dataID];
            object.destroy({
                success: function(object) {},
                error: function(object, error) {}
            })
        });
    })(jQuery);
},
```

Comment: Here's a (slightly simplified) JSFiddle to demonstrate the concept https://jsfiddle.net/antoniodangond/0gcexxgc/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, it's really informative. It didn't work at first but I found out it's because class was being used twice in the span. Once I changed it to <span class="badge delete" it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Oops, I missed that as well! Edited the answer to include that change.